# vuelidate validation object pass as a prop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I have a component that i would like to have the validation object set by passing in as a prop eg this is what i've tried and it doesn't work. The error message in the console is "Cannot read property 'validations' of undefined"

```
export default {
props:{        
    validations: {type:Object, default: {}}                  
},
data(){
    return {

}
},
methods:{


},        
validations: {    
     myObject: [...validations]
}     
}
```

my validations object that i pass in looks like:

```
myValidations:{
item1: {required},
item2: {required}   
}
```

However i dont know if this is possible or if im doing something wrong.
The expected outcome i am looking for is:

```
//other code as above
validations: {    
myObject: {
    item1: {required},
    item2: {required} 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this` inside the script part of the component

```
validations: {    
  myObject: [...this.validations]
}
```

Props name without `this` only work inside the template part.

Comment: There looks like a way if you make the validations object a function then it will execute later and you can get the prop value by assigning it to a computed. https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/08/27/vue-js-form-handling-vuelidate/

Comment: Oh yeah i forgot to change it, i always use validations as a function using validations() {}, and then I use this... and it working